# define variables of types DAY_OF_WEEK and Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY

Tags: java

I am new in Java. How to define **enum** of types `DAY_OF_WEEK` `HOUR_OF_DAY`. I would like to use Calendar object. I do not what to create my own **enum**.
I would like to have the same:

```
  public DAY_OF_WEEK fromDayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Can you explain your question? DAY_OF_WEEK is an int in calendar. _public final static int DAY_OF_WEEK = 7_

Comment: I would like to operate with week days. If I understand right Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK is enum (I maybe not right). I would like to compare, count, etc days of week. I would like to use it as enum (limit amount of constants).

Comment: ohh, now I understand my question. Depend on the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY    everything is int. It's difficult to understand the logic of developers but it looks like I need to write my own class to use Calendar (to manipulate with existing object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to the already provided answers, that if you really want to use an enumeration, you should pass the `int` value as well:

```java
public enum DayOfWeek {
    MONDAY(Calendar.MONDAY), 
    ...;

    private final int dayOfWeek;

    DayOfWeek(int dayOfWeek) {
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }

    public int intValue() {
        return dayOfWeek;
    }
}
```

You also might want to look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) for date/time operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to play directly with `Date` object. You would probably not need to write your own class for using `Calendar`. You can use apache commons [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html). 
Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for this link. The idea is I would like to give ability to user to select a range during the week. For example: select range from Friday 15:00 to Saturday 16:00.

Answer (score 1):

`DAY_OF_WEEK` is not for this. It is for tagging calendar field. For example in [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) method you pass `DAY_OF_WEEK` to specify you want retrieve day of week field of calendar.

P.S. If you want to operate with abstract days of week, use normal `int`, 7-based. If want to tie it to calendar -- use calendars and take only days-of-weeks from them.

Comment: one of the main problem for me is to have restrictions for user when he/she would like to select a day of week.

Comment: you will present him a drop down list or something; how could he/she get out of range?

Comment: for example two dropdown Select "from Day of week" and select "To day of week". And I would like to have a range of selected days.